# INSERT action ON CONFLICT on a postgres table with a hash UNIQUE SHA256 geom

Tags: database, postgresql, gis, postgis, hashset

I have a PostGIS table with a Unique Index geom column.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_uniquegeometry_geom ON environment.fires(SHA256(ST_Normalize(geom)));"""
```

I am trying adding an "ON CONFLICT" action while inserting data to the table environment.fires as mentioned by @Kadir Şahbaz in [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314662/postgis-unique-constraint-for-spatial-equality) as shown below:

```
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT UNIQUE INDEX idx_uniquegeometry_geom DO NOTHING;
```

But PostgreSQL does not acknowledge the WITH on ON CONFLICT action. Could anyone point out the correct way to add this ON CONFLICT action?

Comment: You could try the fine manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html

Comment: @FrankHeikens, I found the solution:

ON CONFLICT (SHA256(ST_Normalize(geom))) DO NOTHING;

Answer (score 0):

```
 ON CONFLICT (SHA256(ST_Normalize(geom))) DO NOTHING;
```